# Cloud-iam Keycloak not working with reverse-proxy

Tags: java, spring, keycloak, openid-connect, reverse-proxy

I want to integrate keycloak with the cloud-iam.com (Keycloak Identity and Access Management as a Service) hoster into my backend application (java spring). My backend app is behind a reverse proxy and all external requests from the backend go through the reverse proxy. I integrated keycloak into my backend and now I have the following issue. I set the `auth-server-url` to my reverse proxy URL and my application is also able to retrieve the well-known document through the reverse-proxy, but all the URLs in the well-known document like token endpoint and authorization endpoint point to the cloud-iam.com URLs and then my backend tries to call directly the cloud-iam.com endpoints, which are then blocked by the firewall.

**I have the following questions:**

1. I would like to know, if there is a possibility to change all the URLs in the well-known document to point to my reverse-proxy URL? If yes where do I have to change it?
2. Do I have to make some changes on my backend application to replace the base URLs in the well-known document?
3. Is maybe a configuration on my reverse-proxy required?
4. Is a configuration on my tomcat server required?

Any help is welcome.